# How can I set the fee rate for raw transactions on Bitcore?

Tags: raw-transaction, bitcore

I'm building a raw transaction. How do I set the relay fee in the Bitcore console wallet?
I'm trying to send a transaction with 2 signatures. I created the transaction and signed the transaction with 2 complete signatures. After I send the raw transaction I get an error message saying `error -26 min relay fee not met`.
Should I type in "settxfee 0.001" to the console before I create the rawtransaction ?

Comment: Do you have a problem with your shift-key?

Comment: Downvoted due to quality, please don't shout at us :)

Comment: I assume that your error message was "min rela**y** fee not met" and corrected what I figured to be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not about `settxfee,` Since you are creating your transaction manually you should consider set transaction fee manually,

let's pretend that your inputs total is 10 BTC Now when you set output amount and destination, you should consider taking out some bitcoins for the fee.

**example:**

> bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"myid","vout":0}]'
>   '{"destination address":**9.99**}'